# add multiple inputs live javascript

Tags: javascript, input, sum

I have many input fields. when i typing in one field it multiplier with a number. how can i make sum of all fields are on the end?

```
$("#100").keyup(function(){
 $("#100_").val(this.value*100.00);
});

$("#50").keyup(function(){
    $("#50_").val(this.value*50.00);
});
$("#20").keyup(function(){
    $("#20_").val(this.value*20.00);
});
$("#10").keyup(function(){
    $("#10_").val(this.value*10.00);
});
$("#5").keyup(function(){
    $("#5_").val(this.value*5.00);
});
$("#2").keyup(function(){
    $("#2_").val(this.value*2.00);
});
$("#1").keyup(function(){
    $("#1_").val(this.value*1.00);
});
```

that is my code for multiplier with number. 
it works. but at the end i have a input field and i want to sum all input fields wit id "*_"

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Where is your script which sum all the multiplier fields? Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strategy: Use also class attribute to help you, for example, define a class moneyInput for each input(#20_, #50_, etc.).

Then, use the following statement:

```
var c,sum=0;
$(".moneyInput").on("input",function(){ 
   $("#"+this.id+"_").val(this.value*parseInt(this.id));
  $(".moneyInput").each(function(){
    sum+=parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  $("#total").val(sum);
});
// the sum will store what you want, I think?
```

And delete all your events which is previously defined.

Comment: thanks but how can i write this sum in a text field at the end?

Comment: What! Just output it!

Comment: how can i do that output in my text field #sum live? i have testet all ways.

Comment: What do you mean by live? You mean whenever users input the one, do the sum? See my edits

Comment: yes that i want. at end is the input #sum and when a user type a number in #5 #2 ... do the sum of #5_ #2_ ... in input #sum

Comment: i have delete all other events and have testet this code but it dont works.